# sub domain and top level page tracking in Google Analytics Page report

Tags: google-analytics

Does google analytics by default includes the pages report for 'www.xyz.com' and 'my.xyz.com' in the page report as single forward slash "/"

```
Example-
page   pageview
/       50
```

can we say that out of 50, 40 were from 'www.xyz.com' and 10 from 'my.xyz.com' ? or will both of them have a separate tracking

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should include both sub domain if Google analytics is installed in both.

One way to view page views per sub domain is to add host name as secondary dimension in the page views report.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts. Do you have any idea how does google records the page name for both? Does it take everything before xyz.com as the pages under forward "/" as default page?

Comment: for ‘page’ it takes the uri mainly whatever comes after the / (including /)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see the domain name as well as the Request URI in your reports, create an Advanced filter for your view like described here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en